# after update trigger not firing based on condition in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a trigger in a table in postgres, whenever a column called `intended_remediation_date` is updated. If after the update this column is `not null` and if another column called `binary_status` = `inactive`, then I want to update the value of my target column , which I call `remediated` to `true`, otherwise it should be `false`.

Here is my function and trigger:

```
create or replace function set_remediated_status() returns trigger as $$
begin
if new.intended_remediation_date is not null and new.binary_status = 'inactive' then
new.remediated := true;
else
new.remediated := false;
end if;
return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

---

```
create or replace trigger update_remediated_status
after update of intended_remediation_date,binary_status on evergreen
for each row
when (new.intended_remediation_date is not null and new.binary_status = 'inactive')
execute function set_remediated_status();
```

The code works, however it fails silently .... suppose the columns looks like that before update:

```
intended_remediation_date   binary_status   remediated
NULL                        active           FALSE
```

Then I update :

```
update evergreen
set 
intended_remediation_date = '2025-03-01',
binary_status = 'inactive'
where id = 1;

intended_remediation_date   binary_status   remediated
2025-03-01                      inactive        FALSE
```

So apparently the trigger is not firing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "after update". When the update is done, you set the variable for a column. But the update is already done. Change the trigger to fire "before update" and everything works fine.

Comment: but postgres can access the `old` and `new` values in `after update trigger` right? I'm confused

Comment: it works, thanks but i don't understand why it works still ....

Comment: Yes, it had both the OLD and NEW values, but it's not going to execute a second UPDATE statement. Your trigger used to fire after the UPDATE. And when the UPDATE is ready, the data is already set in your table. No matter what you do in your function, nothing is going to change that anymore. Unless you execute another UPDATE statement. But that would fire another trigger... Until you run out of resources because that could turn into an endless loop.